# Can't write data to database

Tags: php

I am trying to write a simple application with PHP to write and receive data from a database. I am able to retrieve data already in the database through my PHP script, but I can not write anything to it. When I try, I do not get any errors - just the title of my script and a blank screen.

My code is as follows:

My HTML

```
<form action="insert_book.php" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <p><label for="ISBN">ISBN</label>
            <input type="text" id="ISBN" name="ISBN" maxlength="13" size="13" /></p>

        <p><label for="Author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" id="Author" name="Author" maxlength="30" size="30" /></p>    

        <p><label for="Title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" maxlength="60" size="30" /></p>      

        <p><label for="Price">Price</label>
            $ <input type="text" id="Price" name="Price" maxlength="7" size="7" /></p>      
    </fieldset>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add New Book" /></p>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['ISBN']) || !isset($_POST['Author'])
 || !isset($_POST['Title']) || !isset($_POST['Price'])) {
    echo "<p>You have not entered all the details.<br/>
    Go back and try again.</p>";
    exit;
}

// create short variable names
$isbn=$_POST['ISBN'];
$author=$_POST['Author'];
$title=$_POST['Title'];
$price=$_POST['Price'];
$price = doubleval($price);

@$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'jay', '******', 'Books');

if (msqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo '<p>Error: Could not connect to database.<br/>
    Please try again.</p>';
    exit;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO Books VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $isbn, $author, $title, $price);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
    echo '<p>Submission successful.</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>An Aweful error occured.<br/>
    Nothing was added.</p>';
}

$db->close();

?>
```

Please let me know if you can see any issues.
Thanks!

Comment: use echo $db->error;

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't give any error. I even ran this PHP code through multiple online checkers and it didn't even catch this spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in this line:

```
if (msqli_connect_errno()) {
```

It should be

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
```

You missed a `y`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I must have read through this a million times. This was definitely the problem.